# Calling a value in a PHP array -> vs []

Tags: php, arrays

There is something fundamental I don't understand about PHP arrays.  If I create an array and I want to call a value from that array when and why should I use `$array->item` vs. `$array['item']`?

My array:

```
$fruit_qty = array('watermelon' => 3, 'apple' => 5);
```

If I want the value '5' to print should I use:

```
echo "Number of Apples: " . $fruit_qty->apple;
```

vs

```
echo "Number of Apples: " . $fruit_qty['apple'];
```

My guess thus far is that `$array->item` calls a specific value from the array.  Whereas, `$array['item']` calls and array nested in the array.  So I could potentially do `$array['sub_array']->value`.  Is this correct?

Comment: [PHP objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) != [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) In your example, you _cannot_ do `$fruit_qty->apple`, as you would get _Notice: Trying to get property of non-object_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`->` is an object caller. Since arrays aren't objects then you shouldn't use the `->` code.

Using square quotes is the correct way to retrieve an array value.

Comment: Let's assume I had an empty array called `$fruit_qty`. What would be the difference between `$fruit_qty['apple'] = 5;` and `$fruit_qty->apple = 5;`?

Comment: @fortmac The `->` implies that `$fruit_qty` is an _object_ and _not an array_.  If you attempted to use `->` on an _array_, you would get an error like _Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object_

Answer (score 4):

`->` applies to objects, `[]` applies to arrays. They are two completely different operators and should not be confused.